# How is this bubbling event executed?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm wondering why the output is "1, 2, 1" instead of "1"?

```js
document.querySelector('label').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(1)
})
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(2)
})
```

```html
<label>Click me <input type="text"></label>
```

Comment: You add eventListeners to input and the wrapping label. They BOTH get executed each time you click the label. AND the click on the label triggers the click on the input as it should. What was your expectations? You can use cancelBubble if you do not want this

Comment: But I just Click "Click me", which triggers the listening event on <label>. Why does it trigger the listening event on <input>?

Comment: And if I change the label to div, the result is "1", why is there such a difference?

Comment: That is the special function of an attached label. Clicking it focuses the attached input.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Comment: The problem has been solved. Thanks for your answers.